# Is it possible to use \cline multiple times when using multirow?

Tags: tables, rules, multirow, multicolumn

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}\cline{3-8}
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{}}&\multicolumn{3}{c|}{Singular}&\multicolumn{3}{c|}{Plural}\\\cline{3-8}
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{}&Neuter&Masculine&Feminine&Masculine&Feminine&Neuter\\\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{I}}&Inclusive&\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{O}}&\multicolumn{3}{c|}{X}\\\cline{2-8}
&Exclusive&\multicolumn{3}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{3}{c|}{X}\\\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{II}&Informal&\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{X}&\multicolumn{3}{c|}{X}\\\cline{2-8}
&Formal&\multicolumn{6}{|c|}{X}\\\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{III}&Informal&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{O}}&X&X&\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{X}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{O}}\\\cline{2-8}
&Formal&&\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{X}&\\\hline

\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\label{tab:multicol}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I am using multiple instantiations of `\multicolumn` and `\multirow`, and I was wondering if it were possible to use a discontinuous `\cline` so as not to strike though the O's in the code above. Any tips?

Comment: For reference, see [Should I use `\center` or `\centering` for figures and tables?](http://goo.gl/eePVj)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hhline
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}\cline{3-8}
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{}}&\multicolumn{3}{c|}{Singular}&\multicolumn{3}{c|}{Plural}\\\cline{3-8}
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{}&Neuter&Masculine&Feminine&Masculine&Feminine&Neuter\\\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{I}}&Inclusive&\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{O}}&\multicolumn{3}{c|}{X}\\\cline{2-2}\cline{6-8}
&Exclusive&\multicolumn{3}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{3}{c|}{X}\\\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{II}&Informal&\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{X}&\multicolumn{3}{c|}{X}\\\cline{2-8}
&Formal&\multicolumn{6}{|c|}{X}\\\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{III}&Informal&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{O}}&X&X&\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{X}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{O}}\\\cline{2-2}\cline{4-7}
&Formal&&\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{X}&\\\hline

\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

For example, I've used `\cline{2-2}\cline{6-8}` for a horizontal rule from column 2 to column 2, followed by a break (no line from 3-5) and another horizontal rule from 6 to 8.

Another option for this kind of rule manipulation is provided by [`hhline`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hhline).