# vertical alignment for nested cells in multirow table

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, multicolumn, multirow

This is what I came up with so far:

[image]

I'm trying to achieve the right column to be vertically centered over the parent rows like the cell containing "Puffer" so that the previous columns aren't affected.
I don't really want a fixed length here, because I just want basically a list of items.

Unfortunately it's always aligned at the top and seems to be rendered just inside the first of the multirow cells which crashes the whole design.

I've already tried it with stack and itemize, but I seem to miss something more basic here.

Hopefully someone can help me out here because I can't find a proper or understandable solution anywhere.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,lmargin={2.5cm},rmargin={2.5cm},tmargin={3cm},bmargin={2.5cm}]{geometry}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel} 

\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}

\newcommand{\arr}{$\rightarrow$ }

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{caption}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
%\rowcolors{2}{gray!25}{white}
\begin{tabular}[c]{|c|c|c|}\cline{3-3}
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\multirow{1}{*}{}}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{Inhalt}\\\cline{3-3}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{
                    \multirow{4}{*}{12/2020}}&
                    1. Woche&
                    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{3}{*}{
                    
                    \makecell{\arr Test \\ \arr Test}
                    }}\\\cline{2-2}&
                    2. Woche&
                    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}\\\cline{2-3}&
                    3. Woche&
                    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\arr Puffer}}\\\cline{2-2}&
                    4. Woche&
                    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}\\
                    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Update:

I've added @Bernard's simplified version and added more text to it to see if it still gets aligned correctly.
The code:

```
\begin{table}\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|l|}\cline{3-3}
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\multirow{1}{*}{}}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{Inhalt}\\\cline{3-3}
    \hline
                        \multirow{4}{*}{12/2020} & 
                        1. Woche &
                       \multirowcell{2}{\arr Prepare samples \\[2pt] \arr Implement Feedback}
                       \\\cline{2-2}&
                        2. Woche &
                        \\ \cline{2-3}&
                        3. Woche & \multirow{2}{*}{\arr Puffer} \\\cline{2-2}&
                        4. Woche & \\
                        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

results in:
[image: 3 column table with first col on full height and 4 nested rows on col 2 and 3]

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Probably [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/445128/vertical-centering-in-table) answer might help you. And one hint for later on, please always add a full MWE. In yours e.g. `\documentclass`, `\begin{documnet}` and so on are missing. It really makes it easier to help you if we can simply copy and paste a running code to reproduce your problems.

Comment: Will you add more items later?

Comment: @leandriis yes, I'm planning to add more items later.

Comment: Then the chosen approach with the multirow command in that column will not work properly.

Comment: @Steradiant okay, I've updated my post to make it copy-pasteable (:
However I'm not really getting much out of your mentioned post.

Comment: Contents of `\multirowcell` seem to be horizontally centered. You can overwrite this by using the second optional argument s follows: `\multirowcell{2}[0pt][l]{\arr Prepare samples \\[2pt]\arr Implement Feedback}`.

Comment: @leandriis that did it. 
There is another aspect of the table that I want to ask but I'm not sure if I ought rather open another question for that. To be prezise how can I add more items in the "inhalts" column without destroying the table layout. 
Shall I open another question for that?
I would mark bernhard's answer as solution then, ok?

Comment: @Smittie: As already mentioned in a previous comment, adding more items will not work with an approach based on multirow (or multiirowcell), at least not in a similar way. I would suggest opening a new qeustion specifically on that aspect.

Comment: @leandriis Thanks for clarifying. I did: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/550797/how-can-i-create-an-easily-extensible-table-in-latex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose this simpler code, with a left alignment of the right column (except for the column head):

```
\begin{table}\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|l|}\cline{3-3}
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\multirow{1}{*}{}}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{Inhalt}\\\cline{3-3}
    \hline
                        \multirow{4}{*}{12/2020} & %}&
                        1. Woche &
                       \multirowcell{2}{\arr Test \\[2pt] \arr Test}
                       \\\cline{2-2}&
                        2. Woche&
                        \\ \cline{2-3}&
                        3. Woche & \multirow{2}{*}{\arr Puffer} \\\cline{2-2}&
                        4. Woche & \\
                        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image]

*Edit*: With longer items, the code works as expected:

```
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|l|}\cline{3-3}
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\multirow{1}{*}{}}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{Inhalt}\\
    \hline
                        \multirow{4}{*}{12/2020} &
                        1. Woche &
                       \multirowcell{2}[0pt][l]{\arr Prepare samples\\ 
                       \arr Implement Feedback
                       }
                       \\\cline{2-2}&
                        2. Woche&
                        \\ \cline{2-3}&
                        3. Woche & \multirow{2}{*}{\arr Puffer} \\\cline{2-2}&
                        4. Woche & \\
                        \hline
    \end{tabular}
```

[image]

Comment: This is indeed 98% of what I was looking for. How can I align the content of the "Inhalts"-column to the left no matter how long the text?
I tried changing all relevant cols from `{| c |}` to `{| l |}` but the content remains horizontally centered.

Comment: There are seceral possibilitis. B.t.w., what are the various `\multicolumn{1}{|c|}` for? They result in thicker vertical lines. Is it on purpose?

Comment: I just grabbed them from another example [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132445/is-it-possible-to-use-cline-multiple-times-when-using-multirow) on the forum. So it's not on purpose but I missed this detail till now :D

Comment: @Smittie: I've added  a variant, with a simpler code and some improvements. Please see if it corresponds to what you want.

Comment: Thank you, this looks simpler indeed. However if I produce more text it still remains centered.

Comment: Could you  post an example?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109740/discussion-between-smittie-and-bernard).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want `\arr Test\\ \arr Test` to occupy three rows. If so, you need to let `1. Woche` or `2. Woche` to occupy two rows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}
\newcommand{\arr}{$\rightarrow$ }

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\cline{3-3}
  \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Inhalt}\\
\hline
  \multirow{5}{*}{12/2020} & \multirow{2}{*}{1. Woche}
    & \multirowcell{3}{\arr Test\\ \arr Test} \\
  & &\\
\cline{2-2}
  & 2. Woche &\\
\cline{2-3}
  & 3. Woche & \multirow{2}{*}{\arr Puffer}\\
\cline{2-2}
  & 4. Woche &\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]