# How can I create an easily extensible table in latex?

Tags: tables, tabularx, multicolumn, multirow, makecell

My example table looks like this, but should be easily extensible to implement more nested or merged cells inside.

For instance I want to add more lines to the content of the last column.
Let's say 3 more lines but it shouldn't matter because it could change later anyway.
This tables purpose is for a project expose and should give an overiew of the different milestones that are involved. (just to give an idea how the table might be getting changed later)

Is cal2latex or excel2latex a preferred solution or is this (once the knowledge is there) easily achievable in latex as in any other software without the use of such additional tools?

current source:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{multirow}

\newcommand{\arr}{$\rightarrow$ }

\begin{document}

\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|l|}\cline{3-3}
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\multirow{1}{*}{}}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{Inhalt}\\
    \hline
                        \multirow{6}{*}{12/2020} &
                        1. Woche &
                       \multirowcell{4}[0pt][l]{\arr Prepare samples\\ 
                       \arr Implement Feedback \\
                       \arr Implement Feedback \\
                       \arr Implement Feedback
                       }
                       \\\cline{2-2}&
                        2. Woche& & &
                        \\ \cline{2-3}&
                        3. Woche & \multirow{2}{*}{\arr Puffer} \\\cline{2-2}&
                        4. Woche & \\
                        \hline
    \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Compiled output:

[image]

Comment: If additional lines are in `multirow` cells you must be aware that number of text lines in `multirow` cells should be equal or less than number of text lines in rows spanned by `multirow`. For example you can add to cell with "Puffer" one more line and not more. If you add more, then they will protrude bottom of table.

Comment: @Zarko Ok, but that will probably be the case here. What would be a better approach to takle that situation then?

Comment: The simplest is not use `multirow` cell. However, you can insert fake lines in the second column. To see, what happens, please extend your MWE to case what you like to have.

Comment: The screenshot in your question seems to be produced by code that actually results in an error message upon compiling. If you get an error message, don't look at the output.

Comment: @Zarko I extended it with two more items and tried to insert fake lines but it's broken already. Which package should be preferred to handle this. As I said in my post I want to extend the table easily later on because there could be some items in the future that I'm not aware of now. The plan for the final table is to contain 6 Months but I just implemented one month to showcase what I'm after. Also the height of the middle column crashes with that additional items. Isn't it possible to have everything evenly spaced?

Comment: @leandriis yeah, that's because I tried to implement some fake lines as /@Zarko mentioned before and updated my post with that.

Comment: @Smittie: Dealing with `\multirow` in latex tables usually requires some fine tuning in order to get the desired result. If you have 2 "Woche"  cells and 4 items, you can use something like the following:

Comment: `\begin{tabular}{|c|c|l|}\cline{3-3}
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\multirow{1}{*}{}}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{Inhalt}\\
    \hline
    \multirow{6}{*}{12/2020} 
      & \multirow{2}{*}{1. Woche} 
        & \multirowcell{4}[0pt][l]{\arr Pre.\\ 
        \arr Impl. \\
        \arr Impl. \\
       \arr Impl.
      }
   \\ &&\\ \cline{2-2}
      & \multirow{2}{*}{2. Woche} 
        &  
    \\ && \\ \cline{2-3}
      & 3. Woche 
        & \multirow{2}{*}{\arr Puffer} 
    \\ \cline{2-2}
      & 4. Woche 
        & 
    \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}`

Answer (score 1):

A solution with `tblr` environment of the new LaTeX3 package [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\newcommand{\arr}{$\rightarrow$ }

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{
  colspec = {ccl},
  hline{1} = {3}{solid},
  hline{2-Z} = {solid},
  vline{1-2} = {2-Z}{solid},
  vline{3-Z} = {solid},
  cell{2}{1} = {r=4}{c}, % multirow
  cell{2,4}{3} = {r=2}{l}, % multirow
  vspan = even, % distribute extra spaces evenly
}
        &          & Inhalt \\
12/2020 & 1. Woche & {\arr Prepare samples\\ \arr Implement Feedback\\ \arr Implement Feedback\\ \arr Implement Feedback} \\
        & 2. Woche & \\
        & 3. Woche & \arr Puffer \\
        & 4. Woche & \\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]